# How to enable cut action (and shortcut)?

Tags: copy-paste, shortcut

I am using currently Mac OSX v. 10.9.5 and not being able to cut files or folders is the most stupid thing I have seen in an Operating System, with all respect for this nice OS.

Is there a possibility to enable this shortcut or action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are "Different" on Mac. There's only **Copy** action. Hovewer if You want **Cut** feature, instead of **Paste** You'll need to **Move** the item with shortcut <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.